# Print composer layout changes when converting to PDF

Tags: print-composer

I have the problem of the layout/formatting of my QGIS 2.13.2 in the print converter changing whenever I try to print to PDF Form. 
In the print converter my layout looks good and the shapefile is at the right place. But as soon as I convert it to PDF Form, my shapefile moves a little bit up.

Is it again a problem of georeferencing?

Answer (score 1):

After a long day searching for an answer, I finally found one and it worked.

So I will just repost that answer:

To work around the bug, if you add a map to the Print Composer that contains an OpenLayers basemap, the map must fill the entire page size, without any margin (this is unfortunate, because white space around the map can help visually). To fill the page, go to the map's Item Properties panel (View > Panels > Item Properties, checked on). Expand the "Position and size" section. Note the X, Y, Width, and Height boxes; they define the map's origin point and extension on the page. Since we want the map size to equal the page size, we enter the page size values. For example, A4 paper dimensions are 210 mm x 297 mm (http://www.papersizes.org/a-paper-sizes.htm). So for a portrait-oriented map, enter: X = 0, Y = 0, Width = 210, Height = 297

Comment: If you are using the Open Layers Plugin you might try using the Quick Map Services plugin with the contributed services pack installed instead, if it has the same layer of interest.